# Was every starship refitted as of the 2280s?

Tags: star-trek, uss-enterprise

The original USS Enterprise underwent a refit under the supervision of Captain Will Decker and Chief Engineer Montgomery Scott over the period 2269-2271.

In this time, the Enterprise went from

[image]

to

[image]

which has similar design notes to the USS Reliant, pictured below in 2285:

[image]

**Did *all* of Starfleet's starships receive refits by the 2280s, resulting in a uniform exterior style?  Alternatively, were there any starships in active duty in the 2280s or later that retained a similar appearance to the pre-refit Enterprise?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be much information related to starship refits.  Here is a list of Federation starships which I've found who may have been serving during the 2280s with the pre-refit layout and there is no mention of being refitted:

- [Antares Class](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Antares_type)
- [Federation Class](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Federation_class)
- [Huron Type](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Huron_type)
- [Ptolmey Class](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Ptolemy_class) (potentially; dodgy image)
- [Saladin Class](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Saladin_class)

As an aside, we do know that all *Constitution* class starships [were refitted before the 2280s](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Constitution_class#Refit_history), so it's reasonable to assume some other starship classes were also refitted, however, it is important to note that there were several new starship classes introduced in the 2280s, including the *Miranda* class and *Oberth* class, so some of the aforementioned starship classes may simply have been decommissioned.

So, in conclusion, it is certainly *plausible* that not all starships were refitted as of the 2280s, however the service records of the various ships is unverified, so it seems that, within canon at least, we cannot make a determination.  It seems a reasonable claim, though, to say that there were *some* starships still in operation (particularly of the classes mentioned in the list) by the 2280s that were not of this refitted form.

Comment: "we do know that all Constitution class starships were refitted before the 2280s" - how do we know that? We never saw any other Constitution class starships beside the Enterprise and the Enterprise-A after the end of TOS.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I'm basing that comment off of Memory Alpha which says that; as it relies upon canon information I'm assuming somewhere this fact is stated